# Can we change instance variable name with special character in jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using JAXB and jersey for my project. Here is my model class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="volume")
@JsonRootName(value="volume")
public class Volume{
@XmlAttribute(name="os-vol:name")
public String name;
}
```

Desire Output:

```
{"volume":{"os-vol:name":"vol-1"}}
```

Is there any way so that i could change the instance variable "name" to "os-vol:name" in both xml and json. I used @JsonProperty,but it worked for JSON only. Any other way so that it can represent both JSON as well as XML simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation `JsonProperty`:

```
@JsonProperty(name="os-vol:name")
public String name;
```

Comment: Can I use it for XML representation also or any other tag for XML ??